# Express the differential equation that solves the below problem in polar form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the family of curves that intersect the lines $y=mx$ at a $45^{\circ}$angle

---

I am able to solve this problem by expressing the differential equation in cartesian form 
$y' =  \tan(\arctan(y/x)+45)$
Solving this gives me $r = Ce^{\theta}$

However the question requires us to express the starting differential equation in polar form which doesn't look simple...  Any help ?

Comment: Hint: Express this line in the form; $\mathbf{r}(t) = t\left(1,m\right)^T$.

Answer (score 2):

http://prntscr.com/4gkaoi

i couldnt comment , maybe you should also add the graph ?